# Video inside Html content does not appear on flutter

Tags: html, dart, flutter

I have HTML content which includes texts, images, and videos. The text and images work fine without any problems, but the videos never show up. I have tried many plugins regarding HTML, for example: flutter_html and flutter_html_view, and they all do not show the video.

Sample of the HTML content with video that I want to display:

```html
<p>Hello world 25-3-2019 :</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
    <iframe 
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/W8TrvLoPrfQ" 
        width="400" 
        height="300" 
        frameborder="0"></iframe>
</p>
```

Does anyone have an idea about displaying this content inside a widget?

Comment: If you copy & paste this code on, for example jsfiddle.net it works as expected and the video is shown. You must have more CSS/JS that prevents the video from displaying.

Comment: I'm sorry I forget to mention that I'm displaying it on flutter ...I will edit the title

Comment: What device are you using? Have you tried different devices?

Comment: @Tom Alabaster Yes I have tried different real devices and different android Emulators

Comment: how about use string.indexOf to extract the src of the video, and play it using the video_player plugin, one of my app is using this technique to play videos in my App, But the src is from other websites.

Comment: I have extracted the link using your suggestion...and now the obstacle is how to play the video as it is an embedded video not a regular link

Comment: I have solved the problem by adding the URL directly to the webview under as separated from the rest of HTML content  and it worked and solved the problem....unfortunately I found out that the data that I am receiving can contain more than one iframe and video-like a news article or investigation-and the video should be displayed in the middle, beginning or start of the article if it was found there...I have searched a lot but no package is supporting iframe...

Comment: another way to go is to use the flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.1.5 plugin...I have used it with the same code and it runs fine now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work for you but you can try the `webview_flutter` package. A warning though: it is currently in developers preview, and can be found [here.](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter)

You can give the inline widget some html string to render, for example:

```
WebView(
  initialUrl: new Uri.dataFromString("<p>Hello world 25-3-2019 :</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p
    <p>
    <iframe 
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/W8TrvLoPrfQ" 
      width="400" 
      height="300" 
      frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </p>", mimeType: "text/html", encoding: utf8).toString(),
  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
    _controller.complete(webViewController);
  },
),
```

This code example does require you to pass it a controller: `final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();` and it is also safe practice to dispose of said controller when you are about to dispose the screen:

```
@override
void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  _controller.dispose();
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: First of all thank for your help,but I have reached this point before but it is working as webview, not a normal widget.. besides I can not control the size of the text or the size of the video layout...basically I am displaying the content as web view without the option to change or enhance the style of it...is there any way to control or render  the iframe inside the HTML on flutter?

Comment: _controller does not regocnize dispoase on @override
void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  _controller.dispose();
}